# Prime counting formula considered by S.Wigert

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, primality-test

Consider the following integral:

$$π(n)=\frac{1}{(2πi)}\oint_{C_n}\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx$$

Where ,
$$f(x)=\sin^2(πx)+\sin^2(π(1+\Gamma(x))/x)$$

The integral extends over a closed contour $C_n$ enclosing a segment  $x$- axis from $1$ to $n$ 
and narrow enough to contain no complex zero.

We can clearly see that $f(x)$ has real zeroes only at primes .

This integral is considered by S.Wigert.

> > Question: Is this analysis "resurrectable"? By resurrectable I mean can this be modified such that it may be workable?

Comment: "workable" for what purpose.  No target, goal, path, or intent is specified.

Comment: @EricTowers to get an estimate on $π(n)$.